# Unused argument

Tags: r, datatable

I am trying to understand how `.SDcols` and `.SD` work. I got the following function which I can apply directly in datatable, but not via `lapply`. I am wondering if there is an equivalent with `.SD` which allows to pass multiple parameters to the function body. The below code always gives "Unused argument..."

```
DT <- data.table(a=1:10,b=2:11,c=3:12,ID=c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)))
doSomething <- function(a,b,c){
tmp <- a/b
tmp2 <- sqrt(tmp)^2000000
tmp3 <- tmp2 + tmp
return(rep(tmp3,length(a)))
}
DT[,doSomething(a,b,c)] # works
DT[,lapply(.SD,doSomething,a,b,c),.SDcol=c("a","b","c")]
DT[,lapply(.SD,doSomething,a=a,b=b,c=c),.SDcol=c("a","b","c")]
```

Comment: @akrun I am applying the function for each ID in my panel, thus the requirement for a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to use `.SD`

```
out2 <- DT[, do.call(doSomething, .SD), .SDcols = a:c]
```

which can be otherwise written as

```
DT[, doSomething(.SD[[1]], .SD[[2]], .SD[[3]]), .SDcols = a:c]
```

-checking

```
out1 <- DT[,doSomething(a,b,c)] 
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Comment: ok I see, so do.call just takes the columns one after the other. But when to use lapply then?

Comment: @User878239  when you do `lapply`, it is looping over the data.fraame or `data.table` (.SD - Subset of dat.atable) and it would be a `list` of `vector` values and then you are applying on each vector the `doSomething` where it needs all the vectors/columns as a collective

Comment: @User878239  `DT[,lapply(.SD,doSomething,a,b,c),.SDcol=c("a","b","c")]` here the 'a', 'b', 'c' doesn't exist within that vector.  You can check by `data(mtcars); lapply(mtcars, function(x) x)`

Comment: Thanks, I got it